# Can a CSS code work in all php files if I set the style.css in the header.php but I include header.php in all other php files?

Tags: php, css

So just to be clear the code from the header.php is here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

And if I put this next part in every other php file:

```
include 'header.php';
```

Will the rest of them have access to style.css?

Comment: Yes, they will have access.

Comment: You can easily test this and find out.

Comment: Well I did and it does not work. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. The CSS was not updating so I just had to press ctrl+k for a hard reset.